# A bug in enumerating while another link/picture inserted in the middle.

Tags: bug, markdown

1. lorem ipsum.
2. lorem ipsum

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6qXh.png)

3. lorem ipsum
4. lorem ipsum

[image: picuture]

5. lorem ipsum
6. lorem ipsum

---

Though I used `3.`, `4.`, `5.`, and `6.`, the system however reset the enumeration? unless I put it right after the inserted picture/link, rather than in the newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you completely break paragraphs (double line return), the ordered list starts afresh.  A workaround is as I have done below.  Use two spaces at the end of a line, followed by only a single carriage return (not two).

---

1. lorem ipsum.
2. lorem ipsum
   [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6qXh.png)
3. lorem ipsum
4. lorem ipsum
   [image: picuture]
5. lorem ipsum
6. lorem ipsum

Source:

```
1. lorem ipsum.

2. lorem ipsum  
[link][1]

3. lorem ipsum 

4. lorem ipsum  
![picuture][1]

5. lorem ipsum 

6. lorem ipsum
```

Comment: The effect of a new paragraph can also be emulated by `<br/><br/>`, although some consider that to clutter the source.

Comment: `<br>` is shorter and is what the Markdown processor itself generates. Thankfully, the idea that everything must validate as XML faded out a while ago. `</rant>` @Lord_Farin